# Java SSL javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: internal_error

Tags: java, ssl

I finally managed to get SSL working between clients and my server... Atleast when running it directly from Netbeans.

Client network init code:

```
private Network(final String hostname, final int port) {
    try {
        URL resource = getClass().getResource("/truststore/TCGtruststore.jks");
        if (resource == null) {
            Controller.getInstance().write(MessageType.DEBUG, "Could not load trust store.");
            throw new IllegalStateException("network.Network: Could not load trust store.");
        }
        else {
            Controller.getInstance().write(MessageType.LOG, "Loaded trust store.");
        }
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", resource.getPath());  
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "tcgadmin"); 

        Socket baseSocket = new Socket();
        baseSocket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(hostname, port), Config.TIMEOUT);
        SSLSocketFactory socketFactory = (SSLSocketFactory)SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();
        clientSocket = (SSLSocket)socketFactory.createSocket(baseSocket, hostname, port, true);
        clientSocket.startHandshake();
        out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);     
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
        connected = true;
    } catch (IOException ex) { 
        connected = false;
    }

    waitForServer = new HashMap<>();
}
```

Server network init code:

```
public Server(final int port) {
    this.port = port;
    try {
        URL resource = getClass().getResource("/keystore/TCGkeystore.jks");
        if (resource == null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("server.Server: Could not load key store.");
        }
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", resource.getPath());  
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", "tcgadmin"); 

        //serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
        serverSocket = (SSLServerSocket)SSLServerSocketFactory.getDefault().createServerSocket(port);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Server.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }        
}
```

However when I clean and build it, and run it outside Netbeans, it breaks.
Surprisingly enough the client still behaves fine though, it is the server that starts acting strange with this message:

```
mei 20, 2013 4:36:16 PM server.ServerConnectionReceiver run
SEVERE: null
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: internal_error
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:208)
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:154)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert(SSLSocketImpl.java:1977)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1093)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1328)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:882)
    at sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream.read(AppInputStream.java:102)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:283)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:325)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:177)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:184)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(BufferedReader.java:154)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:317)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:382)
    at server.ServerConnectionReceiver.run(ServerConnectionReceiver.java:45)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Command line code from client:

```
[16:36:15] [Log] Loaded trust store.
[16:36:16] [Log] Could not establish a connection with the server.
```

Does anyone have any clue on what went wrong?

- When server runs from within netbeans and client aswell, everything is fine.
- When server runs from within netbeans and client via commandline, the server gives an exception.
- When I try to run the server from commandline, it gives an error. (I was about to test if it would work with both from commandline, but I unfortunately cannot just test that)

Regards.